# Select first and last column using regex or linux command

Tags: awk, grep

I have [a text file][1] that looks something like this...

```
  ("oo" (set CANDRA-E-O 0) "ऊ") 
  ("o" (set CANDRA-E-O ?ऑ) "ओ")
  ("oa" "ऑ")
  ("au" "औ")
```

I need to extract the first and last columns like:

```
"oo", "ऊ"
"o", "ओ"
"oa", "ऑ"
"au", "औ"
```

I have managed to extract the first column. But not sure how to select the second column.

```
\ {2}\(\".+\"\
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your shown samples/attempts, please try following `awk` command. Written and tested in GNU `awk`.

```
awk -v FPAT='"[^"]*"' '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){printf("%s%s",$i,i==NF?ORS:OFS)}}' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Simple explanation would be, setting `FPAT` to `'"[^"]*"'` which means setting field separator as regex form, from `"` to till next occurrence of `"` comes. Then in main program going through all fields of each line and printing them, when its last field of line then printing new line else printing spaces(to get all one line values into a single line).

Comment: added a new usecase. updated my question.

Comment: @shantanuo, but on what basis `(KP_1)` is being printed in 2nd line? Because what I understood from question we need to print `"` to next occurrence of `"`.

Comment: Yes. You are correct. I will remove that line manually.

Comment: @shantanuo, your welcome, request you to edit your question too, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

With this `awk` solution:

```
awk -v OFS="," '{sub(/^\(/,"",$1);sub(/\)$/,"",$NF);print $1, $NF}' file
"oo","ऊ"
"o","ओ"
"oa","ऑ"
"au","औ"
```

- with first `sub()` we remove the parenthesis `(` of the first field.
- Idem second `sub()` for last parenthesis `)` of the last field.
- we print the two fields separated by comma: `OFS=","`

Comment: The word "table" is returned as second column for comments. question updated.